# Using REGEX REPLACE to group URL paths by first segment

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

How would I use `REGEXREPLACE` to group URL paths based on just the first portion of the path (after the domain):

```
/
/foo/
/foo/bar
/xyz/abc
/xyz
```

The URL's should group as follows:

```
/
foo
xyz
```

My biggest issue with this is how to rename the groups without predefining the group (they should use the matched regex string as the name).

Comment: I understand you are using Google Spreadsheets? Could you please share what you have tried for us not to reinvent what you have already tried.

Comment: I am using Google Data Studio. I haven't got close to being able to  rename URL paths with the string of the first segment in the path.

Comment: Ok, but what was your best attempt? What worked wrong?

Comment: It is hard to guess what you need, try `^/([^/]+).*` and replace with `$1`. It would be easier to help seeing some code of yours.

Comment: Sorry, I have now sort of worked it out. I used regex_extract: REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, '/([^/]+)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may actually use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, '^/([^/]+)')
```

The regex means

- `^` - start of string
- `/`  - a slash
- `([^/]+)` - Capturing group 1 (what will be returned): 1 or more chars other than `/` char.

With a replace operation, you would use

```
REGEXPREPLACE(URL, "^/([^/]+).*", "$1")
```

Here, the rest of the string is matched with `.*` and `$1` inserts the capturing group value into the resulting string.